# Is Metatron actually part of Catholic dogma?

Tags: catholicism, angels, enoch

[Metatron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metatron) is believed by some to be Enoch transformed into an angel. [Some time ago on chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/1167?m=1742355#1742355) someone said that he is part of official Catholic dogma. However, I couldn't really confirm this with a cursory Google search as I keep running into stuff talking about *Jewish* beliefs. Thus, I'm wondering just how official Metatron is within Catholicism?

Comment: Am I the only one that read this as [Megatron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megatron_(Transformers))?

Comment: @Adam: Absolutely not! I did the same the first time and one of my friends had that mix-up a couple hours ago as well. :P

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I am not a Catholic but I will try to answer anyway.

The term *dogma* has a specific technical meaning: it refers to a belief that Catholics are required by the Church to accept. There are many beliefs which are not dogmas, even if they are widely held to be true.

The book *Fundamentals of Catholic Dogma* by Ludwig Ott (1952) is a standard reference. He lists ten beliefs under angelology.

1. In the beginning of time God created spiritual essences (angels) out of nothing.
2. The nature of angels is spiritual.
3. The angels are by nature immortal.
4. God set a supernatural final end for the angels, the immediate vision of God, and endowed them with sanctifying grace in order that they might achieve this end.
5. The angels were subjected to a moral testing.
6. The evil spirits (demons) were created good by God; they became evil through their own fault.
7. The primary task of the good angels is the glorification and the service of God.
8. The secondary task of the good angels is the protection of men and care for their salvation.
9. Every one of the faithful has his own special guardian angel from baptism.
10. The Devil posesses a certain dominion over mankind by reason of Adam's sin.

Among these, 1, 2, 8 and 10 are listed as "de fide", meaning true by reason of divine revelation; 4, 7 and 9 are "sententia certa", meaning theologically certain; 3 is "sententia communis", meaning commonly believed but not necessarily certain; and 5 is "certa" for the fallen angels and "communis" for the rest. No mention here of Metatron, or anything of the sort.

The *Catholic Encyclopedia* says under "Angels" that "no proposition touching the angelic hierarchies is binding on our faith". It refers to *De Coelesti Hierarchia* by Pseudo-Dionysus, and the *Summa Theologica* by Thomas Aquinas, as containing commonly accepted beliefs about the different types of angel; neither of these mention Metatron, or any figure fulfilling that role. All such writings are seen as speculative, and within the domain that theologians can legitimately argue about. Metatron crops up only in the encyclopedia entry for "Kabbala", but the context is explaining that it is a belief held within Judaism.

In conclusion, it seems that Metatron is very far from being Catholic dogma, or even a belief that many Catholics hold.

Comment: The Catechism of the Catholic Church is the authoritative book on what the Roman Catholic Church believes. http://www.scborromeo.org/ccc/p1s2c1p5.htm#I

Comment: @JamesBlack what's your point? Fundamentals of Catholic Dogma, the Catholic Encyclopedia and the Summa will agree in substance. Any virtues the CCC has, it doesn't make it the "definitive" source to the point that everything else pales in comparison

Comment: The one thing that could be added to this answer is that the idea that Metatron is Enoch transformed to an angel doesn't align with Catholic metaphysics about angels or humans

Answer (score 3):

St. Michael, St. Gabriel and St. Raphael are the only named Archangels on the feast of the Archangels on September 29th.

We have no named angels except those three and no public revelation except the Bible, therefore no angel named Metatron.